# Is there a way to log in with Stripe, then send the corresponding customer data to a server?

Tags: express, stripe-payments, supabase

I am designing an application with Stripe. So far, I am using payment links and the customer portal so users can edit their subscription. I am trying to create a server (expressjs) that returns a webpage if the user has a subscription.
I am considering using the authentication capibilities of Supabase or Firebase and let the user log in that way. But since I am already using two no-code solutions from Stripe, is there a way to log the user in and send their subscription status to my express server using only tools from Stripe? I am wondering if there is a simpler, cheaper, and more secure solution than implementing a solution in Supabase.

Comment: If I understand correctly, are you trying to fetch subscription data from Stripe to your Supabase database?

Comment: Yes, and then only the logged in user should be able to access their customer id from Stripe.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're providing access to that particular webpage based on the customer's subscription status. I don't really understand the question whether `is there a way to log the user in and send their subscription status to my express server using only tools from Stripe` - Stripe doesn't have any tools/solutions for authentication on your own website/webpage, you will need to implement this yourself. Typically, you would want to listen to webhooks to receive notifications of subscription activity : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks